# What's wrong with my login form code?

Tags: php

I got this code as part of my login form, but I tried and I can still login without even using a password. I changed everything to be case sensitive, my code seems to have no syntax errors, and I'm stumped.

```
if ($_POST['login']) {

$query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['loginemail'])."' AND password='".md5(md5($_POST['loginemail'])+$_POST['loginpassword'])."' LIMIT 1";
$result= mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row= mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if ($row) {

    $_SESSION['id']= $row['id'];
  header("location:mainpage.php");

 } else {

  $error= "We could not find any user with the submitted informations!";
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging in with different users?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: your login code does not hold against current security practices. Read up on Prepared Statements and have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNdW5HWBhG0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kindly do the following in order to troubleshoot the above

1. Enable error reporting in the beginning of script add below: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
2. var_dump the query and run in phpmyadmin / mysql console - ensure that everything is correct

The above will most likely show the problem if not then do post the corresponding html

Comment: I tried the first one, and got some "undefined index" and "undefined variable" in there.

When I tried running the code on mysql console I got this:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if ($_POST['login']) {

    
    $query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".' at line 1

Comment: Seems like you are not able to receive Post Values which in turns breaking your SQL. Make sure that you receive all values from the form post. This can be done by dumping post values e.g: var_dump($_POST['form_filed']).

Answer (score 0):

I see you have twice the login + password received in your query. Is encrypted twice is not an issue? One hash is enough. For security, `md5 ()` is not the best method, hash () is much better (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.hash.php). Especially with `sha512` for `$algo` parameter. If you mutlitplies `md5`, the imprint will never be good. Example with `md5()` :

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE 
email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['loginemail'])."' 
AND 
password='".hash('md5', $_POST['loginemail']+$_POST['loginpassword'])."' 
LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not checked how many records are present in the result. 
Replace your code with bellow code, will work fine.

```
if ($_POST['login']) {

$query= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['loginemail'])."' AND password='".md5(md5($_POST['loginemail'])+$_POST['loginpassword'])."' LIMIT 1";
$result= mysqli_query($link, $query);


if ($result->num_rows==1) {
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($result);    
    $_SESSION['id']= $row['id'];
    header("location:mainpage.php");
    exit(0);//Best practice to quit the execution after done the page redirection.
 } else {

  $error= "We could not find any user with the submitted informations!";
}

}
```